# Printing the first 30 ASCII characters in c# results in a box

Tags: c#, ascii

Trying to print first 30 Ascii characters in a text box and it results in a box symbol. Any suggestions pls.

Comment: Can you show your code please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are `control characters` and you can't print them all. Read [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) (ASCII)

> ASCII reserves the first 32 codes (numbers 0–31 decimal) for control
>   characters: codes originally intended not to represent printable
>   information, but rather to control devices (such as printers) that
>   make use of ASCII, or to provide meta-information about data streams
>   such as those stored on magnetic tape.

Answer (score 2):

The first 32 ASCII characters are **non-printable control characters**.

Characters that do not have a glyph in a font are usually rendered as a box.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to print has been "remapped" for "historical compatibility" to other code points: read here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437

```
char[] chars = new char[] 
{ 
    '\u0020', '\u263A', '\u263B', '\u2665', 
    '\u2666', '\u2663', '\u2660', '\u2022', 
    '\u25D8', '\u25CB', '\u25D9', '\u2642', 
    '\u2640', '\u266A', '\u266B', '\u263C', 
    '\u25BA', '\u25C4', '\u2195', '\u203C', 
    '\u00B6', '\u00A7', '\u25AC', '\u21A8', 
    '\u2191', '\u2193', '\u2192', '\u2190', 
    '\u221F', '\u2194', '\u25B2', '\u25BC' 
};

this.textBox1.Font = new Font("Lucida Console", 12);
this.textBox1.Text = new string(chars);
```

The font is quite important! Not all the fonts have these "dingbats". `Lucida Console` does.

You should get this output:  `☺☻♥♦♣♠•◘○◙♂♀♪♫☼►◄↕‼¶§▬↨↑↓→←∟↔▲▼`

Note that I'm replacing the `NUL` with a `Space` (the code `\0` with `\x20`) because the textbox isn't very forgiving with `NUL`ls.

I'll add that I wasn't able to find any information on the "automatic" remapping the Command Prompt console does for low ascii characters. It isn't documented very much. (if you try to do `echo ^E` (with ^E = Ctrl+E) and press enter, you will get `♣`, but there is a remapping done here, because my console is using Lucida Console that at code 5 doesn't have a `♣`.)